# How do I to make a model in blender be color customized?

Tags: color

How would I make a model be able to color customized? Example: Warframe you can change individual colors of your character by selecting the color. How would I go about doing this?

If you have a video to explain it that would work too.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What you're looking for is called a colour control map, or a CC texture, which is generally made up of RBG colours. The colours can then be separated by an RBG node and used to control factorial inputs of mix nodes to colour the desired areas.

Comment: **EDIT** Although this example is used for UE4, the principles of how it works within Blender is similar: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Rendering/Materials/HowTo/Masking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 2.79 the color on wireframe mode for the viewport of the object is decided here:
[image]

and on blendee 2.8 you could have wireframe colors per object, like this:
[image]

If you found this is the answer, please mark it up and vote it as answer by clicking on the check mark icon to the left side of the answer. Thanks.

Comment: There's no reason to write asking for accepting the answer. If users find it useful it will be marked / upvoted as one anyway while the answer will be free from any not related content

Comment: Hi Mr Zak. I do this because new users don't know they have to upvote or check the check mark. It´s futile to answer 10+ questions a day and only get +1 point from 2hours work. It´s obvious for the veteran user but not for new ones. Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe this answer has any relevance to the user's question... 'Warframe' wasn't misspelt in place of 'wireframe', they're referring to a recent game that released. Additionally, the question is referring to the colourisation of textures, not viewport shading.